# "Attempted to read or write protected memory." while adding item to List<>

Tags: c#, wpf

Stumbled on strange error. Little bit of research showed that that kind of errors pops up when you tamper with memory from code. I do no such thing.

full error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Cineman.ni.DLL
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

No stack trace available.

Here is some code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Cineman.ViewModels
{
    public class AirTime
    {
        public string Time { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code where error occurred:

```
    public List<AirTime> AirTimes { get; set; }

    public async Task<bool> GetDetailsAsync()
    {
        if (this.Year == null)
        {

            this.IsDetailsLoaded = "visible";
            Uri uri = new Uri(this.DetailsUrl);
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            HtmlNode htmlNode = new HtmlNode(0, htmlDocument, 1);
            MovieData Item = new MovieData();
            string HtmlResult;
            try
            {
                HtmlRequest = await client.GetAsync(uri, _cts.Token);
                HtmlResult = await HtmlRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            if (!(HtmlResult == null) && HtmlRequest.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                await this.DownloadPosterAsync();
                htmlDocument.LoadHtml(HtmlResult);
                this.LargePoster = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='cinema_img']/a").GetAttributeValue("href", "No poster image");
                await this.DownloadLargePosterAsync();
                htmlNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='sessions_day']/table/tbody");
                if (this.Today)
                {
                    foreach (var child in htmlNode.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        var time = new AirTime();
                        //time.Time = DateTime.Parse(child.SelectSingleNode("td[1]").InnerText);
                        time.Time = child.SelectSingleNode("td[1]").InnerText;

                        this.AirTimes.Add(time); //Error fires up here

                        //this.AirTimeText += child.SelectSingleNode("td[1]").InnerText + "  ";
                    } 
                }
                this.IsDetailsLoaded = "Collapsed";
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

What I tried so far:
1. I deleted class and property and made it again. No luck.
2. I commented a code which throws error, Everything works.
3. I unchecked JIT optimization. Does not help.
4. I checked all variables, they are not null, all type casting in place
5. Read a lots of articles and posts about that:)
6. I even restarted pc, phone, deleted Isolated Storage, tried to deploy release package on a phone instead of debug.
What I didn't tried is trying to launch app on emulator, because I have Win 8 and don't have access to my Desktop.

Comment: Which part actually throw exception. Have you debug it ??

Comment: It is in foreach loop. `this.AirTimes.Add(time); //Error fires up here`

Comment: Post part of code where you call this method GetDetailsAsync()

Comment: He's trying to access an uninstantiated public property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't this a public property?

```
 public List<AirTime> AirTimes { get; set; }
```

Create a class variable and instantiate it:

```
private List<AirTime> mobjAirTimes = new List<AirTime>;
```

Then return that from your property.

```
public List<AirTime> AirTimes
{
    get 
    {
       return mobjAirTimes ; 
    }
    set 
    {
       mobjAirTimes = value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The public property shouldn't make any difference, however it will still need instantiating

Comment: @AlSki Either way works.  I like to create private class variables. :-)