# attempted to read write protected memory when adding to list

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a code which should take all pictures from folder, put them into object named "PhotoInspection", add some informations and put this object into list. See the code below

```
private async void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool isOn = tsOnOff.IsOn;
    TextBlock tbChosen = new TextBlock();

    tbChosen = lbInspections.SelectedItem as TextBlock;

    string chosen = tbChosen.Text;

    AllInspectionPhotos aip = new AllInspectionPhotos();

    var folders = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFoldersAsync();

    if (isOn)
    {
        foreach (var item in folders)
        {
            if (item.Name == "ONLINE")
            {
                var inspectionFolders = await item.GetFoldersAsync();

                foreach (var inspectionFolder in inspectionFolders)
                {
                    if (inspectionFolder.Name == chosen)
                    {
                        aip.InspectionEan = chosen;
                        var photos = await inspectionFolder.GetFilesAsync();

                        foreach (var photo in photos)
                        {
                            using (Stream stream = await photo.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
                            {
                                PhotoInspection phtInsp = new PhotoInspection();
                                var bytes = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
                                stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);

                                phtInsp.Photo = bytes;

                                phtInsp.InspectionEan = chosen;

                                phtInsp.PhotoName = photo.Name;
                                aip.Photos.Add(phtInsp);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var item in folders)
        {
            if (item.Name == "OFFLINE")
            {
                var inspectionFolders = await item.GetFoldersAsync();

                foreach (var inspectionFolder in inspectionFolders)
                {
                    if (inspectionFolder.Name == chosen)
                    {
                        aip.InspectionEan = chosen;
                        var photoset = await inspectionFolder.GetFilesAsync();

                        foreach (var photo in photoset)
                        {
                            PhotoInspection phtInsp = new PhotoInspection();

                            using (Stream stream = await photo.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
                            {
                                var bytes = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
                                stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);

                                phtInsp.Photo = bytes;

                                phtInsp.InspectionEan = chosen;

                                phtInsp.PhotoName = photo.Name;
                            }
                            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                            {
                                //await App._client.SendPhotoAsync(phtInsp);
                                aip.Photos.Add(phtInsp); //fires error here
                            });                                
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    await App._client.SendAllPhotosAsync(aip);
}
```

However when I try to add object into list, I get "attempted to read write protected memory" error. PhotoInspection object is filled with relevant data and everything looks good before adding to list. Thanks for any help

Comment: Where are you instantiating the list? Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076423/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-while-adding-item-to-list

Comment: Does the `ONLINE` branch work as expected?

Comment: Yes, I have read it but sadly this solution didnt help. I get the AllInspectionPhotos from service reference.

Comment: I didnt try that ONLINE branch, but it is basically the same code. Photos are stored in app storage folder as well

Comment: The two are subtly different: the `Add()` in the one that is marked is done asynchronously in a task that is queued on the UI thread.  I suspect that, as soon as the `Dispatcher.RunAsync` call returns, control returns to the calling code immediately, which will result in the `AllInspectionPhotos aip` object being disposed (before the `aip.Photos.Add()` lambda gets to run).  Please could you either remove the `Dispatcher.RunAsync` wrapper, or test the `ONLINE` branch and see if the code behaves differently?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the `Dispatcher.RunAsync` call, which returns control to the calling routine as soon as the `aip.Photos.Add()` lambda is *queued*, and not when it has completed.  This results in the `aip` object being disposed before the lambda has actually run.

The [MSDN page for CoreDispatcher.RunAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync.aspx) says:

> [...] it schedules the work on the UI thread and returns control to the caller immediately.

and:

> To spin off a worker thread from the UI thread, do not use this method (CoreDispatcher::RunAsync). Instead, use one of the Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPool::RunAsync method overloads.

It also provides the following code example, and the comment is from Microsoft!

```
//DO NOT USE THIS CODE.
await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
{
   await signInDialog.ShowAsync(); 
});
// Execution continues here before the call to ShowAsync completes.
```